# Can I have an alert when a IPSEC is down in Fortigate 80C?

Tags: ipsec, tunnel, fortigate

We have a fortigate 80c and 60D with an IPSEC VPN .

Is there a way to use the log (or other tool) to send an email alert when the tunnel is down?

I couldn't see anything on the Log & Report tab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have an existing monitoring platform? For VPN tunnels, I tend not to trigger alerts from the endpoint firewalls (e.g. SNMP), but monitor different sides of the link... A ping check from your monitoring solution is pretty darn good for this, as the tunnel will either be up and passing traffic or *down*.

Despite this, you can configure email alerts for [certain functions/events](http://docs.fortinet.com/uploaded/files/1048/fortigate-loggingreporting-40-mr3.pdf) in the Fortigate firewall.

> Configure an alert message that will notify you of activities that are
>   important to be aware about. For example, a branch office does not
>   have a FortiGate administrator so you need to know, at all times, that
>   the IPSec VPN tunnel is up and running. An alert email notification
>   message can be configured for sending only IPSec tunnel errors.

Steps:

Go to Log&Report > Log Config > Alert E-mail. Make sure you have a valid SMTP server configuration. Create a new alert and filter on **IPSec tunnel errors**.